# Is it possible to reuse a deployment from a Mocha Hardhat test script into another one?

Tags: deployment, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, waffle

When testing contracts on Hardhat Mocha stack, every single test js file requires to deploy a set of contracts. Many times this set is exactly the same between different js files. I would like to find a way to deploy them just once for all, and set them back to the initial status on each test file by using a pattern like Waffle fixtures.

Do you think it make sense? Has anybody gone this route? Any hint on how to do that? Thx!

Ref.: [Implementing fixtures with @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68182729/implementing-fixtures-with-nomiclabs-hardhat-waffle)

Comment: Did you figure this out?